# jQuery: Unable to use RegExp to search for exactly "+3.00" or "-3.00"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter

I'm struggling with finding the correct RegExp to match number with plus (+) or minus (-) sign at the end.

I have a select list of number ranging from 0.00- to 40.00- and 0.00+ to 40.00-. I'm using the following RegExp to filter out non matching records:

[image: a list]

```
    $("#MySelectBox").change(function() {
    var filter = $(this).val()
    // If the list item does not contain the numbers phrase fade it out
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp('\\b'+filter+'\\b', "i")) < 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
```

However, it will show both + and - numbers. For example: if filter = 3.00+ then it will return both 3.00+ and 3.00- values.

Any ideas how to get the exact match?

Comment: `\+3\.00` matches `+3.00` but not `-3.00`. Similarly `\-3\.00` matches `-3.00`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I want either \+3\.00 or \-3\.00. What would be the correct RegExp? Since my number is not always 3...but could be any number from 0-40.

Comment: So, you want any number between -40 and +40? Wouldn't it be easier to do a numeric comparison? This is looking like an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I believe the number can be anywhere in a text, not only `-3.00`

Comment: With questions like this it helps ***massively*** if you can provide input value(s) and what the outcomes of the tests on those strings should be.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - You are right. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

So with your brief:

- Check string matches pattern: "+xx.xx" or "-xx.xx"
- Only numbers between -40 or +40
- Omit results out of bounds

This could be a good way to achieve your desired result.

Notes: *(1) Unsure if you wanted to enforce the demical point, (2) there are certainly multiple ways to achieve your result, this is is just one.*

```js
const regex = /^[\-\+]\d+\.*\d*$/;

const tests = ["41", "20", "+20", "-20", "+20.00", "-20.20", "20.20"];

const passedTests = tests.filter(number => {

  const parsedNumber = Number.parseFloat(number);
  const isValid = !!number.match(regex) && parsedNumber > -40 && parsedNumber < 40;
  
  console.log(`Test ${number}, result: ${isValid}`);
  
  return isValid;
});

console.log(passedTests);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question to be more precise. How would you implement your solution on my code?

Answer (score 0):

`[\+-]\d{1,2}\.00`

Will match `+` or `-`, followed by one or two digits (`\d{1,2}`), followed by `.00`.

However, RegExes don't have "greater than 40" kind of logic. They only match patterns.

There are useful tools to help you, like [Rexegpal](https://www.regexpal.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried it but it won't return any results. I've updated the question to be more precise. How would you implement your solution on my code?

Comment: Why not simply `$(this).text().includes(filter)` then ?

Comment: Well, I did try includes (and contains) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, but `$(this).text()` is the `<select>`'s text, but it has no text. It can't work. `this` is the `<select>` element

Comment: No, I didn't post the full code. `$this.text` refers to `$('.number_field').each(function() {`

Comment: Well the full code woul definitely help. You should eit your original question and create a code snippet in it (there's a button for that), so you actually provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To get an exact match for a number with plus (+) or minus (-) sign at the end and from 0.00- to 40.00- and 0.00+ to 40.00+, you can use:

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]|[123]\d)\.\d\d|40\.00)[+-]$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `(?:[0-9]|[123]\d)` Match either a digit `0-9` or a number 10 - 39
  - `\.\d\d` Match a `.` and 2 digits 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `40\.00` Match `40.00`
- `)` Close group
- `[+-]` Match either `+` or `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q3f9fd/1)

In Javascript you can use

```
const regex = /^(?:(?:[0-9]|[123]\d)\.\d\d|40\.00)[+-]$/;
```

If the value is not the only value in the string, you could start with pattern with a word boundary `\b` and assert a whitespace boundary at the right `(?!\S)`

```
\b(?:(?:[0-9]|[123]\d)\.\d\d|40\.00)[+-](?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ryCDiy/1)